# Recording a video using OpenCV and IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv

```
void captureVideo()
{
    int codec = CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1');
    CvSize size = cvSize(640,480);
    CvVideoWriter * vwriter = cvCreateVideoWriter("test.avi", codec, 15, size);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        getImageData((BYTE*)m_pRgb->imageData, m_pRgb->imageSize, -1);
        cvShowImage("video", m_pRgb);
        cvWriteToAVI(vwriter, m_pRgb);
    }
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&vwriter);
}
```

I have to use IplImage instead of mat for this project unfortunately, and I was able to get live view working, get images to work, but videos I cannot. In this code, `m_pRgb` is my frame of type `IplImage *`. It's meant to capture 100 frames and save it as an AVI. It saves the AVI, but the AVI won't play in anything.

Comment: Have you tried other CV_FOURCC codes, like DIVX, MP42 or DIV3 ? [There](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) you can find mode codes.

Comment: @AlekseyPetrov No luck, unfortunately. I've tried five.

Comment: What size m_pRgb has? Maybe, not 640x480?